# Issue with assigning the passed value from another ViewController to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring, nsurlrequest

I got a value from another ViewController. I can print this in log but here the problem is I am getting the value in this format

```
 (
     201  )
```

I am getting this value from JSON data. I can't able to get the value in UITextField. At the same time its not working with urlstring i.e I mentioned requested string in below code.

```
NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&CategoryId=%@&Continent=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&Gender=%@&ImageName=%@&AgeRange=%@",PassedUserId,CategoryId,continentTextfield.text,countrytextfield.text,citytextfield.text,gender,imagename,ageTextfield.text];

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserImage.svc/InsertFacialImage?%@",requestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData;
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);
```

i need to run NSUrlRequest along with that string.

Answer (score 1):

If your log is the result of a NSLog, it seems your number is encapsulated into an array. Try to cast the variable you are logging as a NSArray, retrieve the first object and cast it as an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting value like Array format from JSON data. You need to get them in NSArray and get the value by retrieving the first object of array as below code. As I don't know how you are getting that value. From dict or other source..

```
NSArray *tempArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"201", nil]; //Replace this the code you are getting that value(or)
NSArray *tempArray=[dict objectForKey:@"Value"];//If you getting from dict
NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@Value from Array is:%@",[tempArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSString *userIdString=[tempArray objectAtIndex:0];//If you want value in string format
int userId=[userIdString intValue];// If you want in Integer format
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

you are getting wrong format of JSON data. The JSON data u fetching including with ( ). check the JSON in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/. make changes in connection did finish loading

```
NSError *err;
NSString *JSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"jsonImage:%@" , JSON);

jsonDi = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

compareId = [jsonDi valueForKey:@"ImageId"];
```